# Can I use Google Play Developer API to get warnings about my APK?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

When I manually upload an APK to the Google Play Console, I sometimes get useful warnings like this:

[image]

Is it possible to get similar warnings from the Google Play Developer API?

I have a CI job that uploads my APK to the Play Store daily, so I can make sure there are no issues with it. I'd like to have the job inform me if there are any warnings like the one above.

It uses a script like [this](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/blob/master/scripts/basic_upload_apks_service_account.py), which uses the [Edits.apks.upload](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/apks/upload) and the [Edits.tracks.update](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/tracks/update) methods, but I don't see any place where the APIs might return warnings.